# Testing GPS current location on Android mobile phone

Tags: android

When, I test this code on my android mobile phone the current location doesn't show up.  Should I configure my mobile or increment new code into the code to allow it run on my mobile properly.  A hint will be much appreciated. the code is as follows

```
public class GetLocation extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    double latitude,longitude,accuracy;
    private  LocationManager lm;
    private LocationListener lo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
        lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lo = new mylocationlistener();
        tv.setText("waiting for location");
        if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){

            createGpsDisabledAlert();  

          }

    }


    //dialog to check if gps enabled or not
    private void createGpsDisabledAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS is disabled! Would you like to enable it?")
        .setCancelable(false) 
        .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS", 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ 
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){  
                 showGpsOptions();  
            } 
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Do nothing",  
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){  
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                     dialog.cancel();  
                   }
                    }); //close negative builder

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  
        alert.show();  
             }


    private void showGpsOptions(){  
         Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
         android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
         startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);  

    }

     private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            if (location !=null){


            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                  /*
                    Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", latitude + "");
                    Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", longitude + "");

                    */ String str = "\n CurrentLocation: "+
                        "\n Latitude: "+ latitude + 
                        "\n Longitude: " + longitude + 
                        "\n Accuracy: " + accuracy; 

                      Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      tv.append(str);               

            }

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
             Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,"Error onProviderDisabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
             Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,"onProviderEnabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
             Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this,"onStatusChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }


    public void onResume(){
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lo);  
        super.onResume();


    }



}
```

Comment: no everything is working fine but the coordinates do not show up when toast

Comment: So, the "satellite" icon appears in the status bar and you wait quite a long time for the location to be determined, right?

Comment: Are you using the Google APIs sdk? Although that might just be for the emulator.

Comment: i wait for 30seconds but nothing appears.  when i test it through DDMS its working fine. i'm not using google api but just want to get latitude longitude and altitude display.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate you need to call lm.requestLocationUpdates() to get your location listener working . See [Requesting Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#Updates)

Comment: Also, I just have to ask, is your TextView a single line? If this is the case it might be updating but you can't see it because the text goes beyond the extents of the TextView.

Comment: The package crash if lm.requestLocationUpdates() is placed onCreate. If i put onResume() in onCreate() method, is this an equivalent ? i tried it works but never knows.

Comment: Can you verify that your onLocationChanged() function is ever being called?

Comment: Also, do you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> in your manifest?

Comment: How about changing your onResume so that the super gets called first:

` public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lo);
 }`

Comment: yes everything is settle well yet no GPS location getDisplayed on the mobile phone. Also should i register gps tracker from samsung to use fully the gps device in android ?